# Does the speed of Openlayers depend on the number of GeoJSON layers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, layer

I have a simple map with ~8000 objects from GeoJSON files. I noticed that when I distribute these objects into 10 files and 10 vector layers, the map seems to load faster than if there is only one file and one layer. All ten files are very different: from 5 objects in one to ~7000 in the other.

Is this explained by some Openlayers rules or mechanics? Or it shouldn't be like this at all?

I played a little with minZoom of different layers, and it seems that this also obviously speeds up the work of the site. Unfortunately, the option with WebGLPointsLayer does not seem to suit me.